# This is a ruby file , I would like to ask why my junior sales cannot adding to other?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
class SalesAgent
  attr_accessor :sname, :stype, :samount

  def initialize (name, type, amount)
    #complete initialize() function
    @sname = name
    @stype = type
    @samount = amount
  end
end

def main

  # create a new array
  sale = Array.new
  # repeat the following all the 4 sales agents
  input = "Yes"
  while input == "Yes"||input == "yes"
  puts "Input agent name:"
  # get input from user
  sname = gets.chomp
  
  puts "Input agent type (Junior/Senior):"
  # get input from user
  stype = gets.chomp

  
  puts "Input sales made by this agent (RM):"
  # get input from user (float type)
  samount = gets.chomp.to_f
  sales = SalesAgent.new(sname, stype, samount)
  sale << sales
  juniorsum(sales)
  puts "Key-in another agent data ? (Yes/No)"
  input = gets.chomp
  end
  # create the new SalesAgent object from the input above
  # add the new SalesAgent object into the array
  # call display() function
  sale.each {|sales| display(sales)}
  # call juniorsum() function
  juniorsum(sales)
  # print total sales made by all the junior sales agents
  sleep(1)
  puts "Total sales made by junior is RM " + juniorsum(sales).to_s
end

# This function receives an array as parameter
def display(sales)
  puts "Name: #{sales.sname}"
  puts "Sales: #{sales.samount.to_s}"
  puts ""
  #display names of all the sales agents and their individual sales amount 
end

# This function receives an array as parameter 
# It calculates and returns the total sales made by all the junior sales agents
def juniorsum(sales)
  if sales.stype =="Junior"||sales.stype == "junior"
  total = total = sales.samount
  end
  return total  
end
main
```

Comment: Tip: `while input.downcase == 'yes'`, or even better, `input[0].downcase == 'S'`. Use this pattern whenever matching strings that are case insensitive.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Note: Ruby does not need, nor should have a `main` method. Just put that code in the `main` context, which is to say, not within a method.

Comment: It's worth noting that variable names like `sale` to represent a list of sales, and `sales` to represent a single salesperson are *highly confusing*. I'd recommend calling those `agents` and `agent` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your sales total method is only operating on one entry, not the list as I think you intend. Fixed it looks like:

```
def juniorsum(sales)
  sales.select do |s|
    s.stype.downcase == 'junior'
  end.inject(0) do |sum, s|
    sum + s.samount
  end
end
```

Where that uses `select` to find all "junior" sales, then `inject` to sum up the `samount` values. This *filter* and *reduce* pattern is quite common, so it's worth studying and using whenever you're facing problems like this.

Note to call it you'll need to pass in the array, not a single entry:

```
puts "Total sales made by junior is RM #{juniorsum(sale)}"
```

Note you call that method twice, once for no reason. If you want to interpolate in a string use the `#{...}` interpolation method. No `to_s` required!